# IsEnabled binding for the auto-generated DataGridCheckBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, binding, autogeneratecolumn, isenabled

I have a DataTable in the view model and DataGrid bound to that DataTable with option `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` and `AutoGeneratingColumn` event implemented in the view code-behind. In this event I make decision to show or not to show some particular columns  and configure some additional properties for auto-generated columns. All those columns appeared bound to appropriate DataTable columns during run-time. The question is - how can I setup additional binding for the `IsEnabled` property of a checkbox within newly added `DataGridCheckBoxColumn`?